# Duplicate IDs causing interference between tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I am looking at converting a legacy application to use jQuery UI Tabs (using AJAX to acquire the data for each Tab).

We are able to, easily, configure the legacy application to only respond with the HTML "guts" of the page, without the HTML for the surrounding header, left, right and footer panes, and the performance improvement (perceived and actual) is significant, plus it makes the application look a lot slicker and more up-to-date.

However, the legacy application uses 3 separate pages for database CRUD operations:

Page-1 : Criteria form - which posts to:
Page-2 : SQL Query and display Results - with links to:
Page-3 : Form for maintenance of record with DELETE and SAVE options

and there are duplicate IDs, Form Names and FormField Names on all three original pages. Changing the legacy application to make the IDs unique would be a huge amount of work (vast number of such pages), so I would like to work around it if possible.

My first attempt was to "move" the innerHTML from a Tab to an associative array when it loses focus, and reinstate it when the tab gets focus. This works fine from a display perspective, but it seems to break all the Javascript associated with the underlying code (once it has been moved to associative array and back again).

Before I start trying various other approaches I would appreciate any experiences / suggestions you may have. My thoughts are:

A. Sort out whatever is broken by the method I am using
B. Apply a PREFIX to all the Names/IDs when the Tab loses focus, and remove the PREFIX when the tab gets focus.

but maybe there is a better way?

Many thanks for your help.

Other info:

The legacy application has OnClick calls to JS functions [for actions such as SAVE, DELETE, FIND, etc] that assume fixed names for Forms etc. and Validation of the form has JS that defines rules based on names of FormFields ... so changing that across the system would be a lot of work, and require lots of QA testing, hence I am keen to find another route if possible

Comment: Duplicate `id`s are not supported in any version of HTML and they are going to cause you problems no matter what.

Comment: If I move the HTML out of the lost-focus tab before the got-focus tab has its HTML replaced; or similarly rename the IDs just-in-time, there won't be any DUPs will there? Or maybe I'm missing something more fundamental?. Just trying to reuse the Legacy app on this occasion, I agree for a new project avoiding the issue completely would be much better :)